# How can I reach level 5 biomass on Meadow if I destroyed the Ledon seeds?

Tags: waking-mars

I accidentally destroyed the Ledon seeds trapped at the bottom of Meadow while trying to get them out from under breakable rock. What can I do to max out the biomass on that level if I don't have Ledon seeds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following three species have the largest biomass values:

- Ledon Zoa - 35 (50 when on Enriched Terrain)
- Halid Zoa - 20 (40 when on Enriched Terrain)
- Prax Zoa - 40 (requires Acidic Terrain)

You should be able get to the highest biomass level on Meadow using only **Prax Zoa** and **Halid Zoa** using [plenty of **Compost**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123713/waking-mars-how-do-i-get-enriched-terrain-and-compost/123714#123714).

The level also contains **Phyta** which only provide 5 biomass each, but will continue to grow in population so long as they are well fed, which should happen automatically if you have enough Halid Zoa producing seeds.

Comment: You can also just grab some seeds somewhere else and bring them back if you need them.

Comment: @GnomeSlice - Not the Ledon Zoa seeds, those are the large seeds that float and cannot be picked up.

Comment: Oh, right.  Yeah.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this map was/is incredibly easy. The pods holding seeds on them?
Stand on the side and they will plant for you! There are phytes everywhere and cycots to build up. Each phyla takes one seed, which, if you have lots of Halids like i do, you can farm em, and +5 biomass each. i have like hundreds.
I also love contributing to Cycot communities.