# How do I get Enriched Terrain and Compost?

Tags: waking-mars

Is it possible to create your own **Enriched Terrain** (also known as **Fertile Terrain**), or are you stuck with the ones provided? And related, where do I get more **Compost**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enrich existing terrain by throwing **Compost** on it (note that this will not work for Acidic or Barren terrain). Terrain can be enriched even if there is already a plant growing there.

Compost is producded when a **Phyta** is eaten by a **Larian**; the Larian then spits out the corpse of the Phyta which you *cannot pick up*. You need to wait about 10 seconds before the corpse breaks down, and leaves behind Compost which you *are able to pick up*.

The best level to produce compost on is **Larian Gauntlet**, where there are plenty of places to corral the Phyta into the Larian tentacles. It's a dangerous level, so make sure to keep the Phyta on that level well fed so they aren't all killed off.